# My Code inserts only first row data in sqldatabase

Tags: vb.net, ado.net

How do I insert data of second row in SQL Server database? Here is my code:

```
Private Sub InsertStockDatagrid()
          con.Open()
        
            Dim cmdsrl As New SqlCommand("Select Code, Qty, Rate, Amt, Taxable, cgstamt, sgstamt,Type,Prefix,Srl,Branch FROM stock", con)
            cmdsrl.Parameters.AddWithValue("Type", ComboBoxTranType.SelectedItem.ToString())
            cmdsrl.Parameters.AddWithValue("Prefix", Lblprefix.Text)
            cmdsrl.Parameters.AddWithValue("srl", TextINVNo.Text)
            cmdsrl.Parameters.AddWithValue("Branch", LBLBranchcode.Text)
    
            Dr8 = cmdsrl.ExecuteReader()
            If (Dr8.Read()) Then
                    MessageBox.Show(" Unique field checked")
                dr.Close()
    
            Else
                   For Each Rw As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows
                    'For RW As Integer = 0 To DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1
                    Dim cmd = New SqlCommand("Insert into Stock (Code, Qty, Rate, Amt, Taxable, cgstamt, sgstamt,Type,Prefix,Srl,Branch) values('" & Rw.Cells(15).Value.ToString() & "','" & Rw.Cells(6).Value.ToString() & "','" & Rw.Cells(7).Value.ToString() & "','" & Rw.Cells(13).Value.ToString() & "','" & Rw.Cells(13).Value.ToString() & "','" & Rw.Cells(11).Value.ToString() & "','" & Rw.Cells(12).Value.ToString() & "','" & ComboBoxTranType.Text & "','" & Lblprefix.Text & "','" & TextINVNo.Text & "','" & LBLBranchcode.Text & "')", con)
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                Next
    
                MessageBox.Show("Stock Data Entered")
                con.Close()
                Updatestocksrl()
    
            End If 
End Sub
```

Comment: You're doing a lot wrong there but, unrelated to the specific question, you should not be calling `ExecuteReader` and `Read`. By doing so, you are retrieving data that you never actually use. If you were going to call `ExecuteReader` then you would just test `HasRows`, which will tell you whether there are records in the result set or not without reading any data. Better still, refactor your SQL to return a count or a Boolean value and call `ExecuteScalar` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Don't loop through the rows of `DataGridView` at all. Create a `DataTable` with the appropriate schema, populate it with initial data if appropriate and then bind it to the grid via a `BindingSource`. When it comes time to save the data, call `Update` on a `SqlDataAdapter` - the same one you used to retrieve the data if you did actually retrieve data - to save the changes from the `DataTable`. In its simplest form, that might look like this:

```
Private table As New Datatable
Private adapter As New SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM MyTable", "connection string here")
Private commands As New SqlCommandBuilder(adapter)

Private Sub GetData()
    adapter.Fill(table)
    BindingSource1.DataSource = table
    DataGridView1.DataSource = BindingSource1
End Sub

Private Sub SaveData()
    Validate()
    BindingSource1.EndEdit()
    adapter.Update(table)
End Sub
```

Comment: Should a declare for the binding source be somewhere? Missed you!

Comment: @Mary, the BindingSource should be added to the form in the designer, just like the `DataGridView`.

Comment: Sir Thanks for giving Solution to my Question, but Still i am not able to solve it The first Select query i have return to prevent violation of primary key, and pls explain me the Datagridview data inserting in sql database, should i remove query 'For each Row as Datagridview, Pls help me out, Thanks Sir

Comment: @SanjayJarad, there is no such thing as a `DataGridView` inserting data to a database. The grid displays the data and allows the user to interact with it. That's it, that's all. I have already helped you out by showing you everything you need to do. You retrieve data from the database into a `DataTable` and you save changes from that `DataTable` back to the database. What you do in between is irrelevant to that. That said, I've shown you what to do in between, i.e. bind the `DataTable` to the grid. Stop trying to create a problem where there isn't one. I've shown you want to do. Do it.

Comment: *"The first Select query i have"* is irrelevant to this answer. I addressed that in a comment on the question because it wasn't related directly to the question. Don't try to discuss it on an answer that doesn't involve it.